# lsblk + how to print only the disks that are without filesystem

Tags: awk, filesystems, rhel, udev, lsblk

we want to print only the disks that are without *filesystem* by command line

from following example we can see that `sde` disk is without filesystem

```
lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE
NAME               FSTYPE
sda
├─sda1             xfs
└─sda2             LVM2_member
  ├─vg-LV_root   xfs
  ├─vg-LV_swap   swap
  ├─vg-LV_var    xfs
  └─vg-LV_docker xfs
sdb                ext4
sdc                ext4
sdd                ext4
sde
```

so we try the following command in order to capture the disks without FS

```
lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE | awk '$2 == "" { print $0 }'
```

and we get

```
sda
sde
```

as we can see from above `sda` disk printed , but `sda` is the OS disk , so command line not gives the right output

right output should be :

```
sde
```

any suggestion or other approach to gives the right output?

```
lsblk -oNAME,FSTYPE,FSTYPE --noheadings --nodeps
sda
sdb  ext4   ext4
sdc  ext4   ext4
sdd  ext4   ext4
sde
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that we add fdisk (and some simple help tools) to lsblk in the method. The following shellscript works in my test case,

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(lsblk -dno name|grep -v sr)
do
 LANG=C
 sudo fdisk -lu "/dev/$i" |
  tr '\n' ' ' |
   grep 'Disk ' |
    grep -v 'Disklabel type:' |
     grep -o "/dev/$i"
done
```

This identifies a clean drive (without any disklabel alias partition table).

If you wish to see drives with a partition table and partitions, but no file system (and no swap space) in any of the partitions, try the following shellscript, that uses only lsblk (and some simple help tools),

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(lsblk -dno name|grep -v sr)
do
 LANG=C
 echo -n "/dev/$i "
 lsblk -lno fstype "/dev/$i" | tr '\n' ' '
 echo ""
done | sed 's/ *$//' | grep -v '\ [a-z]*'
```

Edit:

If you sometimes want to see a CD/DVD drive, remove `|grep -v sr` from the 'for-line'. This works well in the second alternative (but not in the first one because fdisk can throw you out from the do-loop with "fdisk: cannot open /dev/sr0: No medium found").

Comment: As soon as you do `tr '\n' ' '` to replace all newlines with blanks the content is no longer a valid text file as it no longer has a terminating newline and so what `grep` or `sed` or any other text processing tool does with it is undefined behavior. If you want to convert all newlines to blanks then you could do `awk -v ORS=' ' '{print} END{printf "\n"}'` and that'd also avoid the undesirable trailing blank that the `tr` would add.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @EdMorton :-) I don't know awk well enough yet, but I'm sure that many tasks can be done easier and better with that way. I'll put learning awk on my todo list.

Answer (score 2):

Just based on the input/output in your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF == 1 { hits[$1] }
/^[^[:alpha:]]/ { delete hits[prev] }
{ prev = $1 }
END {
    for ( name in hits ) {
        print name
    }
}

$ cat file | awk -f tst.awk
sde
```

Obviously replace `cat file` with `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for `PTTYPE` too, partition table isn't a filesystem. You can also use `--no-deps` to remove all the child devices if you are interested only in disks:

```
$ lsblk -oNAME,PTTYPE,FSTYPE --noheadings --nodeps | awk '$2 == "" && $3 == "" { print $0 }'
sdb
```

but this also depends on your definition of "disks that are without filesystem" -- as I said a partition table isn't a filesystem so your command gives a valid result for that and then there's a question whether a disk with a partition table with partitions is empty or not. If you expect this to return a disk with partition table but without partitions, you'll need to used something more complex than `lsblk` for that.

Comment: I still get sda from command line

Comment: I also update the Question

Comment: You wrote `FSTYPE` twice: `-oNAME,FSTYPE,FSTYPE`, it's `PTTYPE`: Partition Table TYPE.

Comment: yes I get - lsblk: unknown column: PTTYPE,FSTYPE ( I have RHEL 7.6 )